# AutoIT GUI and text output

Tags: user-interface, autoit

My GUI and program work but just not as expected, so hear me out.

I wrote this program to take user input in the form of 1-10 example words for 3 categories.

The purpose of it is to output a text file with every triad permutation.

Unfortunately it is outputting permutations that aren't triads.

It isn't very much code, why is this happening?

ex.

GUI:

Colors      Numbers     Greek-letters

Red         One         Alpha
Blue        Two         Beta

output:

red one alpha
red one beta
red two alpha
red two beta
blue one alpha
blue one beta
blue two alpha
blue two beta

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>

$windowWidth = 600
$windowHeight = 430

$textFieldVertSpacing = 30

GUICreate("Semantic Intuition/Idea Naming Tool", $windowWidth, $windowHeight) 

GUISetBkColor (0xB0E2FF)

GUICtrlCreateLabel("Category A", 80, 10)
GUICtrlCreateLabel("Category B", 260, 10)
GUICtrlCreateLabel("Category C", 450, 10)

$categoryA = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*0)+(150/4)*1, 40, 150)
$categoryB = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*1)+(150/4)*2, 40)
$categoryC = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*2)+(150/4)*3, 40)

$example0 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*0)+(150/4)*1, 80)
$example1 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*0)+(150/4)*1, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*1)
$example2 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*0)+(150/4)*1, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*2)
$example3 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*0)+(150/4)*1, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*3)
$example4 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*0)+(150/4)*1, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*4)
$example5 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*0)+(150/4)*1, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*5)
$example6 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*0)+(150/4)*1, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*6)
$example7 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*0)+(150/4)*1, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*7)
$example8 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*0)+(150/4)*1, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*8)
$example9 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*0)+(150/4)*1, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*9)

$example10 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*1)+(150/4)*2, 80)
$example11 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*1)+(150/4)*2, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*1)
$example12 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*1)+(150/4)*2, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*2)
$example13 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*1)+(150/4)*2, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*3)
$example14 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*1)+(150/4)*2, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*4)
$example15 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*1)+(150/4)*2, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*5)
$example16 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*1)+(150/4)*2, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*6)
$example17 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*1)+(150/4)*2, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*7)
$example18 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*1)+(150/4)*2, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*8)
$example19 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*1)+(150/4)*2, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*9)

$example20 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*2)+(150/4)*3, 80)
$example21 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*2)+(150/4)*3, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*1)
$example22 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*2)+(150/4)*3, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*2)
$example23 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*2)+(150/4)*3, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*3)
$example24 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*2)+(150/4)*3, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*4)
$example25 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*2)+(150/4)*3, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*5)
$example26 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*2)+(150/4)*3, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*6)
$example27 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*2)+(150/4)*3, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*7)
$example28 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*2)+(150/4)*3, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*8)
$example29 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", (150*2)+(150/4)*3, 80+$textFieldVertSpacing*9)

$generateTriadButton = GUICtrlCreateButton("Generate", ($windowWidth-100)/2, $windowHeight-40, 100)

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

Global $examplesA[10] = [$example0, $example1, $example2, $example3, $example4, $example5, $example6, $example7, $example8, $example9]
Global $examplesB[10] = [$example10, $example11, $example12, $example13, $example14, $example15, $example16, $example17, $example18, $example19]
Global $examplesC[10] = [$example20, $example21, $example22, $example22, $example24, $example25, $example26, $example27, $example28, $example29]

GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)                     


While 1

    Switch GUIGetMsg()
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit
         Case $generateTriadButton
            permutate()

            Exit
    EndSwitch

WEnd

Func permutate()

    $a = 0
    $b = 0
    $c = 0
    $x = 1

    $empty = ""

    $output = FileOpen(@ScriptDir & "\TriadOutput.txt", 2)

    While $a < 10
       while $b < 10
          while $c < 10


               ;MsgBox(0, "String length is:", StringLen($examplesA[$a]))
               If (StringStripWS(GUICtrlRead($examplesA[$a]), 8) <> "") AND (StringStripWS(GUICtrlRead($examplesB[$b]), 8) <> "") AND (StringStripWS(GUICtrlRead($examplesA[$a]), 8) <> "") Then

               FileWrite($output, $x)
               FileWrite($output, ")")
               FileWrite($output, " ")
               FileWrite($output, GUICtrlRead($examplesA[$a]))
               FileWrite($output, " ")
               FileWrite($output, GUICtrlRead($examplesB[$b]))
               FileWrite($output, " ")
               FileWrite($output, GUICtrlRead($examplesC[$c]))
               FileWrite($output, " ")
               FileWrite($output, @CRLF)

               $x = $x + 1

               EndIf

             $c = $c + 1
          WEnd
          $c = 0
          $b = $b + 1
       WEnd
       $b = 0
       $a = $a + 1
    WEnd

    FileClose($output)
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical Copy-Paste-Error.

Just replace the second $a in your last If-Statement (line 94) with $c and it works as expected...

You find this out by verifying the output. The problem is, that every third text field is taken into account but the other two words work just fine. So the error must be in the expression (condition) responsible for the third field. And this is just in line 94...

Comment: Oh, and you can simplify much of your code. For example, write a function, that creates a GUICtrlCreateInput with just two parameters, the row and the column count. And then use two for-loops to call each of them, placing the results in an array of inputs.

And you should use the "&" to concatenate two strings for your output into your file, so you just need one function call of FileWrite like ($output, $x & ") " & GUICtrl....)